# Leather cord- joining whilst under tension for drive

Tags: leather

I have a hand crank wheel that uses a thin leather cord to transmit power to another wheel. How do a join the cord together in a loop whilst on the machine under slight tension?

Comment: Hi Pablo, can you post a picture of what you're talking about?

Comment: Are you trying to knot the cord while it is on the pulleys instead of making the loop and then putting on the wheels? Guessing that the machine is not active while you are doing this...

Answer (score 2):

I assume what you have is similar to a treadle powered sewing machine. Luckily there's still quite some interest in these antique machines, so you can find some tutorials online and you can even buy leather transmission cords in several online stores.

The transmission cords are usually joined by a metal clip or piece of thick wire that is bent in place. Most cords you can buy already include this clip on one end.

These instructions are from this [Treadle Belt Replacement Tutorial](https://freemotionproject.com/2019/08/treadle-belt-replacement-tutorial.html) (emphasis added by me):

> Once you get the belt in place, **overlap the end with the clip with the long end and pull it nice and firm – not tight – around the wheel** on your sewing machine and treadle wheel. **Mark a line where the ends of the treadle belt overlap**.
>
> Now release the clips and shift the long end of the belt over to a convenient place you can work on it. The little narrow spot to the right of the machine is just too tight!
>
> Use the nail to make a hole in the end of the belt and tap it through with your hammer over the block of wood. You want it as perfectly in the middle as possible, not at an angle. Yep, using these Treadle Belt Pliers would probably make this a lot easier!
>
> With the hole created, place the belt back around the treadle wheel, and double check it’s fitting around the sewing machine properly too. Insert the metal clip into the hole and check the fit. The belt can fit a bit tight to start as it will loosen slightly as you use it.

There are other instructions like:

- [This wordpress article](https://sewingwithtreadles.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/how-to-put-on-a-treadle-sewing-machine-belt/) (includes images)
- [This YouTube video by Leah Day Quilting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXEoZIBserE)
- [This YouTube video by SewMachines](https://youtu.be/zst8TQtHwd0)

And you can find many more by searching for "how to install treadle belt".

Since leather is slightly elastic and has a good grip, it should suffice to pull the cord snugly around the wheels while measuring the required length. You should not pull so much that the cord is constantly under high tension. However, leather is an organic material and will slightly change over time. **It is perfectly normal to have to shorten a new transmission cord after 1 - 2 months.**

If you need it to fit even tighter, it *might* be possible to soak the cord in water (to make it more pliable) and let it dry on the wheel (which makes it contract). But it could just as well ruin your belt, so no guarantees.